# Objects keep disappearing, even though the HitTest object is removed

Tags: actionscript-3

I have been trying to create a game in actionscript 3, but am stuck on one problem for the past 4 hours.
Every time you press a key a block appears, color depends on which key you press, when enemies hit that block they dissapear. I made it so that the enemies get removed through removeChild and the block itself dissapears after 1 second, but the problem is that after the block gets removed the enemies still die, even though the block isn;t visible anymore, so here I am.

I use this code in Vechtblok.as (This is the block that appears to kill enemies), I add this code by adding a eventListener to a timer named sterf, this is the function:

```
public function gaWeg(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        blok.parent.removeChild(blok);
    }
```

In Vijand.as (The enemy class) I have this code for them to dissapear, I give the enemies this code through adding an eventListener:

```
public function aanval(e:Event):void
    {
        if(hitTestObject(Vechtblok.blok))
        {
           teken.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, beweegHor);  
           trace(String(watbenik));
           teken.parent.removeChild(teken);

           //removeChild(Vechtblok.blok);
        }

    }
```

I think the error should be there somewhere, but my head hurts too much from the time I spend on trying to fix it.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my broken English.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code and what I can understand from it, you're not updating your code such that `Vechtblok.blok` is no longer referring to the same block after it removes itself. `hitTestPoint` and `hitTestObject` checks for collisions using the bounds of the objects, regardless or whether or not they are on the stage.

Judging from the static variable `Vechtblok.blok` you only support one block at a time. Once the block is removed, that variable is still pointing to it. It's just no longer displayed on the stage. Your collision code is still checking against that same block.

You will have to modify your code something like this:

```
public function gaWeg(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        blok.parent.removeChild(blok);
        blok = null;
    }
```

;

```
public function aanval(e:Event):void
    {
        if(Vechtblock.blok != null && hitTestObject(Vechtblok.blok))
```

This way the collision check only happens when there actually is a block.

Comment: Hey TreeTree, this worked, but when I create another block through the command it gives me an error that it can't point to a object that is null.

Comment: Well I don't know what your code looks like and that's no longer related to this particular question.